# objective in policy gradient equation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, probability

[image]

I don't understand how this was deduced from first equation to second expectation. Is it from conditional probability theory? I checked but still can't understand. From wikipedia, the expectation of a continuous variable X is:

[image]

But how could that be correlated? I mean I can take $r(s,a)$ as variable $x$, but why that $\pi_{\theta}(s,a)$ could be taken as $f(x)$? Thanks a lot for any hint or link or book for reference.

Comment: Never mind, it's because $\pi(\theta)$ is the probability density. It is exactly the definition.

Comment: This site encourages self-answers. If you have time to write an answer about this it might be appreciated by someone else who had the same initial reaction as you. Although your comment is too short to use as-is, if you do answer, you should aim to write a paragraph or so to explain the insight you got, maybe taking 5 mins over it.

Comment: I understand. I actually didn't deduce in detail so I didn't make it an answer. To have it in mathematical correct formular requires quite some efforts. I just take it as granted since I'm not that familiar with this join distribution equations. I'll see if I have a better understanding later to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\tau = (\mathbf{s}_1,\mathbf{a}_1,...,\mathbf{a}_T)$ is a sampled trajectory from $\pi_\theta(\tau)$ with return $r(\tau)=\sum_{t=1}^{T}r(\mathbf{s}_t,\mathbf{a}_t)$ then we **define** the expected reward (our cost function) as:

$$J(\theta)\equiv E_{\tau\sim \pi_\theta(\tau)}[r(\tau)] = \int \pi_\theta(\tau)r(\tau)d\tau$$

where $\pi_\theta(\tau)$= $\pi_\theta(\mathbf{s}_1,\mathbf{a}_1,...,\mathbf{a}_T)=p(\mathbf{s}_1)\prod_{t=1}^{T}\pi_\theta(\mathbf{a}_t|\mathbf{s}_t)p(\mathbf{s}_{t+1}|\mathbf{s}_t,\mathbf{a}_t)$.

Notice that the p.d.f $\pi_\theta(\tau)$ here  is a joint probability distribution over states and actions. Thus the expectation comes from:

$$E[X]=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} xf(x,y)dxdy$$

and this is the reason that you need to integrate over the volume of states and actions. $p(\mathbf{s}_1)$ is a distribution over initial states and independent of the integration over actions so it can get out of the 2nd integral. Taking the log of the joint distribution $\pi_\theta(\tau)$, substituting into $J(\theta)$ and differentiating both sides of the first equation,  you get an equation w.r.t the $\theta$ parameters and quantities that you can compute so you can estimate the gradient of $J(\theta)$.

I am not very familiar with your notation (i think you found it in a master thesis) but this is the general approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through later and take it as accepted later. My notation is from David Silver's famous paper as I recall.